# Find the number of solutions in integers(x,y) of the equation $x^2 y^3=6^{12}$

Tags: number-theory

Find the number of solutions in integers(x,y) of the equation $x^2 y^3=6^{12}$ ??
My try follows

$x = ±2^a*3^b$ and$ y = 2^c*3^d$

for some integers a,b,c,d ≥ 0

$(±2^a*3^b)^2* (2^c*3^d)^3$= $2^{12}*3^{12}$

$(2)^{(2a+3c)}* (3)^{(2b+3d)}$ = $2^{12} *3^{12}$

$2a + 3c = 12$

$2b + 3d = 12$

Now , how can i get the values of  $a, b, c , d $

And what the pairs of (x,y) should be?

Thank you  for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction on $a,b,c$ or $d$ other than your equations. So we can have any $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ that satisfy the equations.
So

$a=0, c=4$

$a=3, c=2$

$a=6, c=0$

and

$b=0, d=4$

$b=3, d=2$

$b=6, d=0$

so we can have any combination of the above.

So we have $18$ total solutions as we can have $\pm x$.

Comment: Agreed, I'll edit

Comment: but  answer is  18 pairs

Comment: This probably because we can have $\pm x$ which I did not include, sorry for that